# Concatenate thousands of columns using UNITE

Tags: r, tidyverse, multiple-columns

I have a data frame (allgen) with nrow > 10k and ncol > 40K.
I would like to concatenate all columns in a single variable using UNITE. It works but it takes time. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it:

```
# nrow(allgen) = 11824
# ncol(allgen)= 42153

#set first and last column

names(allgen)[2]-> start
names(allgen)[ncol(allgen)]-> end

system.time(allgen %>%
        unite("S",start:end,sep='')-> test)


user system elapsed
192.35 0.03 193.01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)
setDT(allgen)
allgen[, result := do.call(paste0, .SD)]
allgen
```